# multi drop down wordpress not fitting, scroll not working

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, overlay

Referring to this site: http://premierdisab.staging.wpengine.com/

On the header nav menu when you hover over "Medical Conditions" found under "Social Security Disability" on the top nav bar it does display all conditions but not all fit. I tried adding to the class "sub-menu" the attribute "Overlay-y: scroll" but it didn't work. It applied to the first dropdown but then hid the second drop down which could only be accessed by an x-axis scroll that was now showing.

Is there a way in WordPress to give a unique drop down a specific class? I have a feeling that would do it but I can't figure out how after looking at the menu settings on the WP Dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this to your stylesheet:

```
.nav-menu .sub-menu .sub-menu {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: That didn't quite work. However I instead added the code below and it worked just as I wanted. Thanks! 

.nav-menu .sub-menu .sub-menu {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 450px;
}